# Multiple threads passing parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, instance-variables

Having:

- class CPU() {};
- void executable() {} , inside CPU; this function is executed by a thread.

  ```
  void executable(){
    while(run) { // for thread
     cout << "Printing the memory:" << endl;
     for (auto& t : map) {
           cout << t.first << " " << t.second << "\n";
     }
    }
   }
  ```

Need to instantiate 5 threads that execute executable() function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    threads.push_back(thread(&CPU::executable, this)); //creating threads


cout << "Synchronizing all threads...\n";
for (auto& th : threads) th.join(); //waits for all of them to finish
```

Now, I want to create:

```
 void executable0 () {
     while(run) { 
       cout << "Printing the memory:" << endl;
       for (auto& t : map) {
             cout << t.first << " " << t.second << "\n";
       }
     }
   }

 void executable1 () {....}

to executable4() {....}  // using that five threads that I`ve done above.
```

How could I do? **Initialize or using std:thread constructor**?

Can someone give me an example to understand this process.
Thanks & regards!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], I have very little clue what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have no idea what the goal is here.

Comment: Do you mean you want e.g. `thread(&CPU::executable0, this)`, `thread(&CPU::executable1, this)` etc. for all the `executableX` functions? Without a mapping from the "index" to a specific function that's not really possible in C++.

Comment: yes; sorry if I confused you, I`m new here

Comment: With the above said, please edit your question to tell us the *real* problem you need to solve? *Why* do you need something like that?

Comment: Having this function executable(), I need to instantiate 5 threads that will work in parallel - to execute some code

Comment: Lastly, the some of the only few ways to solve the problem you have the way you want it to be solved, is either to have a map from index to function (as I already mentioned); Not having a loop at all, and just create the threads explicitly; Or pass in the index into a single thread function, which then use a switch statement (or similar) to call the actual function.

Comment: Use a lambda...

Comment: @rustyx Can you give me an example?

Comment: `threads.push_back(thread(&CPU::executable, this)); //creating threads`. This creates **and starts** threads. `for (auto& th : threads) th.join(); //starting threads` this doesn't start threads. This waits for all of them to **finish**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following **Some programmer dude**'s comment, I would also advise using a standard container of `std::function`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class CPU {
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> executables{};
    std::vector<std::thread> threads{};

public:
    CPU() {
        executables.emplace_back([](){
            std::cout << "executable0\n";
        });
        executables.emplace_back([](){
            std::cout << "executable1\n";
        });
        executables.emplace_back([](){
            std::cout << "executable2\n";
        });
    }

    void create_and_exec_threads() {
        for(const auto executable : executables) {
            threads.emplace_back([=](){ executable(); });
        }

        for(auto& thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }
};
```

We create a `vector` holding three callbacks, which will be used to initialise `thread`s and start them inside `create_and_exec_threads` method.

Please do note that, as opposed to the comment in your example, creating a `std::thread` with a callback passed to its contructor will not only construct the `thread`, *but also it will start it immediately*.

Additionally, the `std::thread::join` method does not start the the `thread`. It waits for it to finish.